# AngularJS centralized data with restful services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, service, controller

I need help with the design of my AngularJS application.

I have a factory, which provides a resource object for me, to a restful web service.

```
product.factory("productResource", function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource("/fooo/rest/products/:id", {}, {
        query: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    });
    return resource;
});
```

I have a service, which provides a method, to query all products from the resource factory.

```
product.service("productDao", function (productResource) {
    this.getProductModel = function () {
        var data = productResource.query(function () {
        });
        return data;
    }
});
```

The controllers invoke the service, to get the data they need:

> Controller 1

```
header.controller("header.selection.product", function ($scope, productDao) {
        $scope.products = null;
        productDao.getProductModel().$promise.then(function (result) {
            $scope.products = result;
        });
    });
```

> Controller 2,3,4...

They look nearly the same, but they're using the data for different purposes.

Now i don't know a correct way, to implement a "datasource", which is accessed from all controllers. I don't want to make a request for all the data, for each controller startup, it should only be made once.

How can i automatically change data of all other controllers, when a product gets  updated in one controller, the service should do an update (not implemented yet), when the update was successful they "centralized data" should change, and all controller data with it.

I read about using rootScope for this purpose, but some people say, don't just create factories/services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$http` with the cache option, only one of your controllers will make the "real" request, all the others will get the products from the cache.

`$http.get(url, { cache: true })`

Or you can `emit` the results from inside your factory and let the controllers listen that.

```
  getProducts: ->
    url = productsApiEndPoint

    $http.get(url, { cache: true })
      .then(
        (data) ->
          $rootScope.$emit('YourFactory.getProducts', data);
        (error) ->
          //handle error
      )
```

I prefer the first approach. Its more clear.

You can use the [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and coordinate the data flow. Create a service that will be your mediator, emit from that service to your controllers when the data arrives. Emit from a controller to that service when the controller change the data and then the service will emit back to the rest of the controllers

On your factory emit the data to the mediator service:

```
product.factory("productResource", function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource("/fooo/rest/products/:id", {}, {
        query: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    });

    resource.query(...)
    .$promise.then(function(products) {
      $rootScope.$emit('ProductsFetched', products);
    });
});
```

On your mediator service listen and emit to the controllers.

```
product.service("productDao", function (productResource) {
   $rootScope.$on('ProductsFetched', function(data){
     $rootScope.$emit('ProductsChange', data);
   });

   $rootScope.$on('ProductsChangeFromControllers', function(data){
     $rootScope.$emit('ProductsChange', data);
   });
});
```

On your controllers listen and emit to the mediator service:

```
header.controller("header.selection.product", function ($scope, productDao) {
        var products = null;
        $rootScope.$on('ProductsChange',function(data){
           products = data;
        });

        // do something with the products
        $rootScope.$emit('ProductsChangeFromControllers', products);

    });
```

Maybe there are some syntax mistakes, but I just wanted to give you an idea how to structure it.

Comment: I want to use the resource object, it makes thinks a lot easier, and how do i share the data between the controllers then, so that every controller changes its data, when another changes ?

Comment: @Synturas although `$http` is more flexible and not "difficult" as it seems, I updated my answer with the `$resource` service. Hope it helps